# Recursion with Concurrent.futures library

Tags: python, concurrency, concurrent.futures

I could make it work with asyncio module but I'm really struggling this one. Is this because instead of creating multiple threads inside the main function, this structure is creating a main thread, then a thread inside that, then another thread inside that...?

```
executor = cf.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10)

i = 0

tasks_list = []


def f(x):
    global i
    print("Task starting for {}".format(i))
    time.sleep(x)
    if i < 10:
        i += 1
        print("Creating new task {}".format(i))
        task = executor.submit(f, x)
        tasks_list.append(task)
        # inner_future = executor.submit(f, x)
        # cf.wait([inner_future])
    print("Done sleeping for {}".format(i-1))


future = executor.submit(f, 5)
tasks_list.append(future)
cf.wait(tasks_list)
#time.sleep(30)
executor.shutdown(wait=True)
```

This is the result I am getting:

```
Task starting for 0
Creating new task 1
Task starting for 1
Done sleeping for 0
Creating new task 2
```

When I uncomment the time.sleep statement at the bottom, the result is of this pattern:

```
Task starting for 0
Creating new task 1
Done sleeping for 0
Task starting for 1
Creating new task 2
Task starting for 2
Done sleeping for 1
Creating new task 3
Task starting for 3
Done sleeping for 2
Creating new task 4
Done sleeping for 3
Task starting for 4
Creating new task 5
Task starting for 5
Done sleeping for 4
Creating new task 6
Task starting for 6
Done sleeping for 5
Creating new task 7
```

It stops for 5 seconds after every "Task starting for..." and then runs "Creating new task..." (for the next i value) + "Task starting for..." (for the next i value) almost immediately and the "Done sleeping for..." (for previous i value).

As per the Python docs: the submit() method schedules the callable, fn, to be executed as fn(*args, **kwargs) and returns a Future object representing the execution of the callable).

Here it seems, the child thread runs immediately the moment the future object is created inside the mother thread, and then when it reaches the time.sleep(x) at the top of the f(x) function, it comes back to the mother thread to run the "Done sleeping..." statement.

Can anyone please explain how the threading works (with concurrent.futures)? So, if I look at it like the stack, a child thread creates atop the mother thread and while it's suspended, it returns control to the mother thread? But if the mother thread runs and finishes, how can the child thread still go back and execute its remainting statements?

---

UPDATE:

I edited the code a bit:

```
executor = cf.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10)

i = 0


def f(x):
    global i
    print("Task starting for {}".format(i))
    print("***************")
    time.sleep(x)
    if i < 10:
        i += 1
        print("Creating new task {}".format(i))
        executor.submit(f, x)

        # inner_future = executor.submit(f, x)
        # cf.wait([inner_future])
    print("Done sleeping for {}".format(i-1))


future = executor.submit(f, 5)
cf.wait([future])
time.sleep(30)
executor.shutdown(wait=True)
```

And this is the result I'm getting:

```
Task starting for 0
***************
Creating new task 1
Done sleeping for 0
Task starting for 1
***************
Creating new task 2
Done sleeping for 1
Task starting for 2
***************
Creating new task 3
Task starting for 3
***************
Done sleeping for 2
Creating new task 4
Task starting for 4
***************
Done sleeping for 3
Creating new task 5
Task starting for 5
***************
Done sleeping for 4
Creating new task 6
Task starting for 6
***************
Done sleeping for 5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\pythonprojects\reqcrawler\test.py", line 70, in <module>
    time.sleep(30)
KeyboardInterrupt
Creating new task 7
```

Around "creating task 3", it starts running the child thread first before running the "done sleeping..." of the mother thread. Why? It still waited 5 secs after that.

Comment: To "schedule" a callable means to execute it immediately if a worker is available or to wait for a free worker if not.

Comment: @MichaelButscher oh okay, that makes sense. Can you please explain how this is working? That'd be really helpful.

Comment: When receiving a new callable by `submit` the pool grabs an idle worker thread if available (or creates a new worker if there are less than `max_workers` around already) and assigns the callable to it which immediately starts executing the callable. If there are no free workers, the pool waits for one and assigns the callable then.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Thanks, got it about the submit() method! Re the sequence of output, I believe the callable is instantly getting called, and then it's meeting the blocking function, time.sleep(). So, when it's waiting, it's returning to the mother thread and running it before creating a new child thread of its own? While I understand these child threads are stacking on top of another because of recursion, are they separate threads on their own?

Comment: The thread does not return while sleeping but other threads have a better chance to run. All created threads have the same chances to run regardless how deep they are nested in a recursive parent-child structure. It seems they don't even record from which a thread was started, so it isn't a real recursion.